# How to get the value after dot in sql query

Tags: sql, split, sql-server-2012

Hi i'm saving file name as a date and time with file extension like below

```
43201612150389.docx,
73201611843471.jpg
```

in my sql table, now I want after dot which extension using sql simple query any one have idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`SUBSTRING_INDEX`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycol, '.', -1)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bcda7/1)

In SQL Server you can use [**`PARSENAME`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx):

```
SELECT PARSENAME(col, 1)
```

Comment: It show error Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3 'SUBSTRING_INDEX' is not a recognized built-in function name.@Giorgos Betsos

Comment: @ChennaRao Are you using MySQL?

Comment: SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT 2012 @Giorgos Betsos

Comment: What does mean `-1` in `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` ?

Comment: @Shafizadeh It means *select from the right*. But this is only valid for MySQL. Check the edit I made for a solution concerning SQL Server.

Comment: # Giorgos Betsos can you please provide me answer in SQL Server ?

Answer (score 1):

MySql:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, '.', -1)
```

SQL:

```
SELECT PARSENAME(field, 1)
```

Comment: It show error 
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'SUBSTRING_INDEX' is not a recognized built-in function name.@M. Suurland

Comment: Are you using SQL server or Mysql? This answer is for Mysql

Comment: SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT @M. Suurland

Comment: Welcome @Chenna Rao :)

Answer (score 0):

if you have all those values stored in table ,numbers table is best way to do it.

```
select substring(@string,n,len(@string))
from numbers
where substring(@string,n,1)='.'
```